# Diffeomorphism invariance and energy momentum conservation

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem, diffeomorphism-invariance, boundary-terms

I was reading Sean Carroll book "Space-Time and geometry", in the appendix B he derives the energy momentum conservation from  the diffeomorphism invariance of the action, however I don't understand a step in the derivation.

I will put some context before asking the question.

He starts with the action for matter fields $S_{m}$ (in the context of general relativity), and takes de variation of the action

$$ \delta S_{m}=\int d^{4}x \frac{\delta S_{m}}{ \delta g_{ab}}\delta g_{ab}+\int d^{4}x \frac{\delta S_{m}}{ \delta \psi} \psi$$
The matter field equations tell us that $\delta S_{m}/\delta \psi=0$, then
$$\delta S_{m}=\int d^{4}x \frac{\delta S_{m}}{ \delta g_{ab}}\delta g_{ab}= \int d^{4}x \sqrt{-g}  T^{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu}\xi_{\nu}$$
Where I have used the definition of Lie derivative (I use the letter $\zeta$ to denote the lie derivative) of the metric 
$$ \delta_{\xi}g_{\mu\nu}=\zeta_{\xi}g_{\mu\nu}=2\nabla_{(\mu}\xi_{\nu)}$$
And the definition of energy momentum tensor
$$T_{ab}=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta S_{m}}{\delta g_{ab}}$$
Next, in the equation (B.25) Sean Carroll makes
$$\delta S_{m}=\int d^{4}x \sqrt{-g}  T^{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu}\xi_{\nu}\\
=-\int d^{4}x \sqrt{-g} \xi_{\nu}\nabla_{\mu} T^{\mu\nu}$$
I don't understand how he can change the covariant derivative, it looks like some kind of integration by parts, but I don't see what happened to the boundary term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boundary terms are always assumed zero in these considerations. After all, non-zero would mean that some energy-momentum is incoming/outgoing. Inside can't be conserved if that's the case.

You can of course write a more comprehensive conservation law by including how much comes in/out (integration over the boundary), but this is not the point here.

Comment: I read that the people assume that $\xi^{a}$ has compact support.